# Unable to delete restore point in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Someone (not me) has created a number of restore points where the name includes a hyphen. For example restore_point-001.

When I try drop the restore point with Drop Restore Point it will error with sql command error saying that it is not properly ended. I have tried putting the name in single quotes and I have tried renaming the name, but v$restorepoint doesn't allow for this.

Is there a way to drop this restore point being named this way?

Comment: What SQL command did you use?

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried putting the name in **single quotes** ...

I'm not a DBA, but what you described reminds me of this:

Let's try to create a *table* whose name contains a "minus" sign (just like your restore point):

```
SQL> create table restore_point-001 (id number);
create table restore_point-001 (id number)
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Nope, it won't work. You said you enclosed the name into single quotes:

```
SQL> create table 'restore_point-001' (id number);
create table 'restore_point-001' (id number)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name


SQL>
```

Nah, it's not a *string literal*.

So, let's try with **double quotes**:

```
SQL> create table "restore_point-001" (id number);

Table created.
```

Ha! It works! Let's now drop it: without any quotes:

```
SQL> drop table restore_point-001;
drop table restore_point-001
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Single quotes:

```
SQL> drop 'table restore_point-001';
drop 'table restore_point-001'
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00950: invalid DROP option
```

**Double quotes**:

```
SQL> drop table "restore_point-001";

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

---

So, yes - I have no idea why people insist on "invalid" characters and what good does `-001` do over `_001`, but - if I were you, I'd try with

```
drop restorepoint "restore_point-001";
```

and see what happens.